# How do I free dynamically allocated memory where each index is also dynamically allocated?

Tags: c, oop, free

For a project, I am trying to implement a matrix "class" in C, but the "destructor" for the matrix is throwing an exception. I am not 100% sure why, though I think it is due to reassigning a variable to two different dynamically allocated pointers and then trying to free the latter one twice. I cannot use C++ for this, but I thought I would try to emulate the functionality as best I can.

Here is the code, I am not including the declarations of any functions or structs that needed to be predefined:

```
struct vComplex {
    double* realp;
    double* imagp;
    uint32_t length ; // for bookkeeping
    BOOL(*isreal)(vComplex);
    void(*free)(vComplex*);
    void(*print)(vComplex*);
}; 

struct mComplex { // complex matrix type
    vComplex* columns; // each vComplex represents one column of the mComplex
    uint32_t nCols;
    uint32_t nRows;
    BOOL (*isreal)(mComplex);
    void (*free)(mComplex*);
    void(*print)(mComplex*);
};

vComplex* createVComplex(uint32_t len) {

    vComplex* x = (vComplex*)malloc(sizeof(vComplex));

    x->realp = (double*)malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    x->imagp = (double*)malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    x->length = len;
    x->isreal = &isreal_v;
    x->free = &vComplex_free;
    x->print = &vComplex_print;

    return x;
}

mComplex* createMComplex(uint32_t nRows, uint32_t nCols) {
    mComplex* x = malloc(sizeof(mComplex));
    vComplex* vp;
    x->columns = (vComplex*)malloc(nCols * sizeof(vComplex));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {
        vp = createVComplex(nRows);
        x->columns[i] = *vp;
    }
    x->nRows = nRows;
    x->nCols = nCols;
    x->isreal = &isreal_m;
    x->free = &mComplex_free;
    x->print = &mComplex_print;

    return x;
}


void vComplex_free(vComplex* x) {
    free(x->realp);
    free(x->imagp);
    free(x); // error occurs here (only when called from mComplex_free)

    return;
}

void mComplex_free(mComplex* x) {
    for (uint32_t i = x->nCols - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        x->columns[i].free(&x->columns[i]);
    }
    free(x);

    return;
}
```

`vComplex.free` seems to work just fine, but `mComplex.free` throws an exception. My intention is that `createVComplex` creates and returns a pointer to a `vComplex` which is then freed by `vComplex.free`. `createMComplex` would allocate memory for `nCols` number of `vComplex` "objects" which would then be freed one at a time. Then the pointer to the array of `vComplex` would be freed and finally the pointer to the `mComplex`. What I think is happening instead is that the first time I call `vComplex.free` inside `mComplex.free` is that it is unable to free the `vComplex` pointer for whatever reason.

Comment: :) LOL this is not OOP.

Comment: I'm curious how you C code "is throwing an exception"!

Comment: &x->columns[i] is that what you intended ? x is already a pointer to dynamic memory

Comment: @KerrekSB I would guess by making the mmu cause the cpu to jump to an exception vector, probably sigsegv or its windows equivalent in response to an attempt to stomp on memory not owned. Exception does NOT have to be a c++ thing, and in fact like much else C++ borrowed the term from well established usage.

Comment: OT: in C, the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` and `realloc()`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.